# How to create a Layout for Tablet

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, tablet

I am making an Android App and have created the basic layout for devices.

But I also want to make the layout for Tablets. I know I can use the different size layouts.

But what should be the ratio of normal layout sizes to the tablet layout size. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are looking for is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) . The value you should be using is 600dp as described in the docs

> res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml  # For 7” tablets or any screen with 600dp
>                                        #   available width (possibly landscape handsets)

So basically you can create a `layout-w600dp` folder inside of the `res` directory to be used as the layout for tablets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what should be the ratio size of views inside the layout.

Comment: I do not think there is any hard and fast rule for that. You can create a layout and play around with the dimensions for that. Test it on different size tablets. What you could certainly do is create a `values-w600dp` and use larger set of dimension values there for it to be used on tablets.

Comment: Thanks vey much for the answer. Accepting it.

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. I have only one layout for each screen which is being used for tablet as well as phones. But what I have done is I have created multiple values/dimes.xml files to alter the values for different screen sizes namely small, normal, large, xlarge. And then reference those values in my layout screen so that they are tablet supported. But Google Play still does not count my app as tablet supported any idea? It shows that the "app may not be tablet optimized". Can you help.

Comment: For your application to be tablet optimized, there are a number of factors. The very fact that you are using "only one layout for each screen which is being used for tablet as well as phones" is against the design principles. You need to make use of the extra screen available on tablet. The manifest should also declare `<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>`.Please have a complete read [here](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have declared `<supports-screens>` in my manifest. Additionally, I am using the dimens.xml to occupy the left out screen space. Suppose I declare `ABC` in my `normal/dimens.xml` to be `1dp` then in my `large/dimens.xml` the value of `ABC` is equal to `1.5dp` which makes sure that it occupies the leftover space. I am using vector images for most of my drawable but I do have some Images which are in png but they don't need to be converted as they are clear enough for tablets. I have tried on real tablet devices. I even have put 7 &10 inch screenshots in Play Store.

Comment: Making a seperate layout means making every layout changes twice or three times. Hence I want to avoid that.

Comment: Again, only using a single layout with larger dimensions to fill the screen is not good use of extra screen space on tablets. You don't have to make every layout twice, just the ones that can utilize the screen on large screen devices, for example : master detail screen can be implemented using two separate activities on a phone while it can be implemented on a tablet using two fragments on a single activity. Now this is effective use of extra screen. Please have a thorough read of the link that I mentioned. These things are mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will surely go through the link. Thanks for the help.